# Django не передает картинки в шаблон

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

В шаблоне вместо картинок отображаются эти значки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В запросах вижу 2 запроса к адресу картинок на компьютере со статусом blocked:other. Картинки хранятся на рабочем столе. Подозреваю, что винда не дает до них добраться.

Вью:

```py
def game(request, id=0):
    if id == 0 or not Game.objects.filter(id=id).exists():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    game = Game.objects.get(id=id)
    photos = GamePhoto.objects.filter(game=game).all()
    return render(request, "game.html", context={
        "name": game.name,
        "desc": game.description,
        "author": game.author.login,
        "photos": photos
    })
```

Шаблон:

```html
{{ name }}, {{ desc }}, {{ author }}
{% for photo in photos %}
    <img src="C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\GameCase\GameCase\{{ photo.photo }}">
{% endfor %}
```